# unable to send Firebase document ID in from VC to VC

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i'm running a query to firebase and i'm able to obtain the documentID but i'm not able to send the documentID over to another VC. I get everything int he query with no issues. I'm not sure what i'm missing. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

**First VC**

```
@IBAction func getDataTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    SVProgressHUD.show()

    if HOSP != (hospNameTxt.text!) {
        ptListQuery = ptListCollectionRef?.whereField("hosp", isEqualTo: (hospNameTxt.text!))
    }

    ptListQuery?.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if let err = error {
            debugPrint("error getting data: \(err)")
        } else {
            guard let snap = snapshot else { return }
            for document in snap.documents {
                let data = document.data()
                let ptName = data[PTNAME] as? String ?? ""
                let assignedMd = data[ASSIGNEDMD] as? String ?? ""
                let officeMd = data[OFFICEMD] as? String ?? ""
                let assignedDate = data[ASSIGNEDDATE] as? String ?? ""
                let seeNoSee = data[SEENOSEE] as? String ?? ""
                let room = data[ROOM] as? String ?? ""
                let app = data[APP] as? String ?? ""
                let documentId = document.documentID
                let username = data[USERNAME] as? String ?? ""
                let userId = data[USER_ID] as? String ?? ""

                let newPtList = PTList(ptName: ptName,
                                       assignedMd: assignedMd,
                                       officeMd: officeMd,
                                       assignedDate: assignedDate,
                                       seeNoSee: seeNoSee,
                                       room: room,
                                       app: app, documentId: documentId,
                                       username: username, userId: userId
                )
                self.ptListInCell.append(newPtList)
                print("docID", documentId) //this shows the documentID in the console
                print(document.data()) //this shows everything in the array but the document ID
            }
        }

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToResults", sender: self)
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToResults" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! ResultsdataVC
        vc.ptListFromCell = ptListInCell
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
    }
}
```

**Second VC**

```
class ResultsdataVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, PatListCellDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var resultsTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var patientFilter: UISegmentedControl!

    var ptListFromCell = [PTList]()
    var ptDatasToPass = [PTData]()
    var selectedFilter = FilterCategory.hosp.rawValue
    var patientListener: ListenerRegistration!
    var patientCollectionRef: CollectionReference!
    //segmentedControl
    var dataFilter = 0
    var tableDataSee : [String] = ["Yes"]
    var tableDataNoSee : [String] = ["No"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        resultsTableView.delegate = self
        resultsTableView.dataSource = self
        resultsTableView.rowHeight = 110

    }
```

here is PTList model:

```
class PTList {

    private(set) var ptName: String!
    private(set) var assignedMd: String!
    private(set) var officeMd: String!
    private(set) var assignedDate: String!
    private(set) var seeNoSee: String!
    private(set) var room: String!
    private(set) var app: String!
    private(set) var documentId: String!
    private(set) var username: String!
    private(set) var userId: String!

    init(ptName: String, assignedMd: String, officeMd: String, assignedDate: String, seeNoSee: String, room: String, app: String, documentId: String, username: String, userId: String) {

        self.ptName = ptName
        self.assignedMd = assignedMd
        self.officeMd = officeMd
        self.assignedDate = assignedDate
        self.seeNoSee = seeNoSee
        self.room = room
        self.app = app
        self.documentId = documentId
        self.username = username
        self.userId = userId
    }
}
```

here is my db structure

[image]

Comment: Unless I am overlooking something, you are not passing a documentID or even a string to the second view controller, you're *assigning* (passing) an array. Your Firestore closure is populating the `self.ptListInCell` array with PTList objects `self.ptListInCell.append(newPtList)` and then your segue is assigning that array to a variable within the second view controller `vc.ptListFromCell = ptListInCell`. How do you know that var in the second VC doesn't have any data, and more importantly the question is asking about a documentID which is not what you are passing.

Comment: hello Jay, thats my issue that i need to pass the documentID to the secondVC. The array on the secondVC is empty and gets the data from the first VC. ptListFromCell is used to run another query (larger) from the second VC, this is working properly but the documentID is not coming across.

Comment: The documentID is not coming across because *nothing in your code sends or assigns it*. Moreover, in your results viewController, there isn't even a property to hold a documentID.  You need to determine which documentID you want to send, create code that does that via passing it or assigning it and then have var in your results controller to hold that data. As of now, nothing in your code relates to what the question is - if you look at your `ResultsdataVC` there is no var called `documentID`.

Comment: the documentID is declared in the query to Firebase and it is in the PTList model. I'll keep on researching. thank you for looking into it.

Comment: No. There is no documentID being passed. You have an *ARRAY* of *PTList* models that ALL have documentID's and you are passing the *entire array* of objects to the ResultsdataVC, not a documentID.

Comment: if i print to the console after running the query print(documentId) , the ID displays. There is only 1 ID per ARRAY, please see picture above.

Comment: If that's the case it's a mis-use of the for loop since you don't need to iterate over *documents* since you are just reading one document and need to access the fields. Additionally `ptListInCell` is an array and as stated above you are passing an *array*, not a documentID. All of that is unneeded since you are only working with one document. You should really step through you code to see what's happening with your data - you may find you have a lot of unneeded code which is leading to a of confusion.